# i have two fields named as created_at and updated_at(timestamps) and i want to search between these dates in my where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, lumen-5.2

i want to take input date as a parameter and search between the dates that are given in input.

Theses are the timestamps() provided by laravel to create the two fields as created_at and upated_at.I want to search between these dates that are given in created_at and updated_at but unable to find the data between these dates. 
Following is the code that i have create

```
` $startDate = $request->input('created_at');
  $endDate   = $request->input('updated_at');

->select()
->whereBetween('created_at','updated_at',[$startDate,$endDate])
->get();`
```

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: it gives me the following error .But i tried it giving in array but could not find.                                                                Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween() must be of the type array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `whereBetween` only accepts 2 parameters. The first being the column name and the second the array with values to test. Check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

You would want something like:

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate,$endDate])
->whereBetween('updated_at', [$startDate,$endDate])
```

Comment: bro, it gives me null then as it has values between the dates given.. anyhow thanks for you response. i will recheck my code :) and let you know if it works

Comment: @ahmadizhar Could you perhaps should us the whole function?

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween()
>   must be of the type array

is because the second parameter of `whereBetween()` is an array, and you pass a string `'updated_at'` here. So change it to like:

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate,$endDate])
->whereBetween('updated_at', [$startDate,$endDate])
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)